# How to shrink big database files faster than dbcc command?

Tags: sql-server

There is a DBCC command to shrink files of a database. Unless the files are almost empty or the free space is nearly unfragmented this command is often refered as 'don't use'. In rare cases I need to shrink files to a new size. An alternative to the DBCC command in this szenario is what I am looking for.

The databases I'm working on are 'big data': Size of each DB some TB, Size of each file some 100GB.

Comment: Of course you cannot empty, or remove the primary file or filegroup. You might want to consider that in your solution.

Comment: Thats true. I always change the default filegroup to something else than primary to avoid this (and put primary on a minimum size like 10 MB). That's why I forgot to mention. I will add this point. Thanks!

Comment: I do imagine that this may be faster that `DBCC SHRINKFILE` if you have a very large file with a small amount of data - and it should avoid leaving the data in a fragmented state. However, if you're trying to shrink 50 GB off a 500GB file with 100 GB free, I doubt this would actually be faster than `DBCC SHRINKFILE` - and it would certainly require more effort on the DBA's part. Not a knock on the process defined, but on the chosen title....

Comment: Lordy... this question should not be marked as "Off Topic".  It's highly relevant to a very common problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> An alternative to the DBCC command in this szenario is what I am
>   looking for.

One possible alternative to shrink is described in Paul Randal's article:
[Why you should not shrink your data files](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/)

> The method I like to recommend is as follows:
>
> - Create a new filegroup
> - Move all affected tables and indexes into the new filegroup using the    CREATE INDEX … WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON) ON syntax, to move the
>     tables and remove fragmentation from them at the same time
> - Drop the old filegroup that you were going to shrink anyway (or    shrink it way down if its the primary filegroup)

Even if this method will lead to desired result and even more: you'll achieve defragmentation of all your indexes, it is not faster than shrink, it requires additional free space before you can shrink the old files, it can hardly be automated and there will be a problem with LOB data as it will remain in the old FG unless you copy it manually to new FG.

Comment: Thank you for finding the article. It is exactly the recipe the script is following! I tried to add the point more clearly: Rebuild an existing index is something that is not done in the script by now. Build a new clustered index is the esiest way I know to move the structure - if it is possible. With nonclustered index it is very slow. with binary data it is impossible.

Comment: @Christian4143 >>>Build a new clustered index is the esiest way I know to move the structure - if it is possible<<<< It's a WRONG way. And that is what I was trying to explain, but I could not fit it in the comment, so I wrote it in the answer, but then I was asked to remove this explanation. If your idea is TO DROP an existing clustered index and to create a **new one using always the first column of the table**, it's very inefficient and it DISTORTS Randal's suggenstion. Clustered index key is always chosen with care, how can you change it to the first column that you find?

Comment: After your edit your answer is very good: Maybe you could mention that it ony will work when there are clustered indexes on the table. So it is the ideal supplement to my answer!

Comment: @sepupic: You are right. If there already should be an clustered index on the table that is called 'idx1_mover' I would delete it and change the structure of the table. This is not intended in any way. Maybe I should change the name of the index to a more unlikely name.

Comment: @@Christian4143. You cannot substitute clustered index key with just the first column you found in the table. The first column can be a LOB column, or just a field with size greater than 900bytes, and even if it's not so, when you drop clustered index you pass to heap and all the non-clustered indexes are rebuilt. But then you sudenly find that your new clustered index key is the longest, non-unique field that will lead to fragmentation just because it was not chosen with care, so what will you do? Drop clustered index again and this time create it with the OLD key? Why don't do it right away?

Comment: @sepupic: You are the best ever!!! Thank you for that hint. I was just about forgetting it: There is no way to move binary data by creating a clustered index. I mentioned this in my post! Can you read? But I learn a lot here: Shouting loud produces best answers. This is like in real buisiness! Best regards and all the best to you.

Comment: @Christian4143 You do not distinguish LOB data and binary data

Comment: These are the binary formats I know: varchar(max), char(max), XML, text, varbinary and Image. filestream data is binary as well. But this is a differenet storry as well as all columnstore Indexes. I don't know any Differenz between the word LOB and binary data in SQL Server. Maybe you can explain. I will ask a question...

Comment: @Christian4143  char(max) is something that does not exist. All the rest you mentioned is not **binary** data but **LOB** data, you can read about it here: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-lob-data-types. Note this one: "Technically, the VARBINARY data type is not really a LOB data type as it is limited to 8000 bytes. It can be used to store smaller binary data". So, please, call binary as binary and LOB as LOB, and sql world will understand you well